# Right side Space in bootstrap container-fluid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to end right side padding in my container-fluid but I'm not able to achieve this.

As you can see free space which where **red lines** are draws.

I tried many different ways to resolve this problem but don't know from where it's getting this amount of padding?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Airtel Internet Services">
  
    <title>Airtel | Internet Services</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
    
  </head>
  <style>


  </style>
  <body>
     

    <!-- Introducing Airtel black -->
    <style>
      .container-fluid{
        width:100%!important;
      }
      </style>


    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#101010;">
      <div class="row">


    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div style="padding-top:100px;">
      <center>
        <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/black-logo.png" style="width:160px;"><br><br><br>
     <span style="font-size:2rem;color:white;">
     Introducing Airtel Black</span><br><br>
    <span style="color:white; font-size:20px;">Mobile. DTH. Fiber. Combine any two or more services in one plan.</span><br><br>
    <button style="background-color:#4D0D0A;width:220px;color:white;border:none;border-radius:50px;padding:17px;font-size:19px;">JOIN NOW</button>

    </center>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/main-img_new.jpg" style="width:600px;float:right;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2A2A2A;color:white;">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:40px;">

    <span style="font-size:30px;">Airtel Black benefits</span>

    </div>


      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**What I want:** I want to end those spaces completely so that, my image will stick at the right corner of the display.

**Thank you**.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `pe-0` class to the parent element currently marked with the `col-lg-6` class:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Airtel Internet Services">
  
    <title>Airtel | Internet Services</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
   
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
 
    
  </head>
  <style>


  </style>
  <body>
     

    <!-- Introducing Airtel black -->
    <style>
      .container-fluid{
        width:100%!important;
      }
      </style>


    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#101010;">
      <div class="row">


    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div style="padding-top:100px;">
      <center>
        <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/black-logo.png" style="width:160px;"><br><br><br>
     <span style="font-size:2rem;color:white;">
     Introducing Airtel Black</span><br><br>
    <span style="color:white; font-size:20px;">Mobile. DTH. Fiber. Combine any two or more services in one plan.</span><br><br>
    <button style="background-color:#4D0D0A;width:220px;color:white;border:none;border-radius:50px;padding:17px;font-size:19px;">JOIN NOW</button>

    </center>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 pe-0">
      <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/main-img_new.jpg" style="width:600px;float:right;">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2A2A2A;color:white;">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:40px;">

    <span style="font-size:30px;">Airtel Black benefits</span>

    </div>


      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
</html>
```

Learn more about [padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `pe-0` to the `container-fluid` class should remove all the right padding.
If you inspect the container, you'll see that it's coming from Bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your style of writing code is messed. Please use standard style while writing code.

For you question answer is that the col-lg-6 is taking default spacing so make the `margin` and `padding` 0 then it will work. And also make the image width to 100%:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-0">
        <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/main-img_new.jpg" alt="hello"
       style="width:100%;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 m-0 p-0">
    <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/main-img_new.jpg" alt="hello"
   style="width:100%;"/>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: none of these helps in my case don't know why? :(

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly I could say I had the same problem.. I solved it by reducing the overall section size to 98.8vw and the extra padding disappeared. I'm not sure about the risks though.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is being added by the `.row` class, which applies padding on either side of all direct children. The simplest way to override the padding using bootstrap is to add `.pe-0` to the div wrapping the image:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 pe-0">
      <img src="https://assets.airtel.in/static-assets/homes/img/main-img_new.jpg" style="width:600px;float:right;">
</div>
```

If you'd like to remove the padding on all sides of the image use `.p-0` instead.

The bootstrap documentation contains a list of all built in utility classes, which are made for use cases like yours: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/utilities-for-layout/